# AngularJS Error: $injector:modulerr

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue with an angular app. One works perfectly and the second one (with no difference except the variable, app and controllers names) doesn't. I have the following error `Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error`and `Failed to instantiate module ConfigurationApp due to:`...

Here is my html :

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angularLocalStorage-nc/src/angularLocalStorage.js"></script>
<script src="../js/ConfigurationApp.js"></script>
<script src="../js/ConfigurationController.js"></script>
```

Here is the `ConfigurationApp.js`:

```
var ConfigurationApp = angular.module('ConfigurationApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularLocalStorage', 'ui.bootstrap']);

ConfigurationApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
         when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/configuration/index.html',
            controller: 'ConfigurationController',
        });
     }
  ]);
```

The full error is

> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=ui.bootstrap&p1=Error:
>   [$injector:nomod]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.bootstrap
>       at Error (native)
>       at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:417
>       at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:21:412
>       at a (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:21:53)
>       at x.bootstrap (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:21:296)
>       at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:35:116
>       at s (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:302)
>       at g (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:34:399)
>       at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:35:63
>       at s (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:302

Do you know where is the problem ?

Comment: missing } before closing the array ?

Comment: Show the all error message

Comment: @MathieuBertin Nope, just a mistake when I copied my code.

Comment: "due to..." ––– yeeeesss....?!

Comment: @JsIsAwesome I just edited the post and added the url of the all error message

Comment: Follow that link and the link it contains and you end up here: **Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.**

Comment: You forgat to load ui.bootstrap

Comment: @deceze  Thanks, you solved my problem. I removed it because it caused me another problem but i'll make another post.

Comment: How can you spend so much time on posting a question without checking console and reading the actual error so people have to read for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error specifies that `ui.bootstrap` is not available. But the module name is injected properly in the app module

```
var ConfigurationApp = angular.module('ConfigurationApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularLocalStorage', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

But, in your code there is no `ui.bootstrap` script. You need to include that script and it will work

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angularLocalStorage-nc/src/angularLocalStorage.js"></script>
<script src="../js/ConfigurationApp.js"></script>
<script src="../js/ConfigurationController.js"></script>
```